# Stm32 Power consumption in standby mode is too high

Tags: embedded, stm32, sleep, standby

I'm experimenting with standby mode on STM32F4O7VGT6. I know how to put MCU into standby mode(or I think to know that). I'm doing that with this init function:

```
 void MX_RTC_Init(void) { 

    RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime = {0};  
    RTC_DateTypeDef sDate = {0};

    /** Initialize RTC Only  */   hrtc.Instance = RTC;  
    hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;  
    hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv =127; 
    hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255; 
    hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_WAKEUP; 
    hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH; 
    hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN; 
    if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)   {
       Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date */
    sTime.Hours = 0x13;
    sTime.Minutes = 0x20;
    sTime.Seconds = 0x0;
    sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
    sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
    if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
    {
       Error_Handler();
    }
    sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_THURSDAY;
    sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
    sDate.Date = 0x30;
    sDate.Year = 0x20;

    if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
    {
       Error_Handler();
    }
    HAL_PWR_EnableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1);
}
```

This init function allows to weakup MCU from standby mode with wakeup pin(PA0) and with timer(currently period is ~20sec).  Next function is called when I want to put MCU into standby mode:

```
void Enter_StandbyMode(void)
{   
    __HAL_RTC_WAKEUPTIMER_CLEAR_FLAG(&hrtc, RTC_FLAG_WUTF);

    HAL_PWR_DisableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1);
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);
    HAL_PWR_EnableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1);

    HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&hrtc, 40960, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV16);

    HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();
}
```

Again this works as I expect(I used diode to indicate when MCU wakeup from standby mode by timer) but my question is next one:

Why I still have voltage on pins when MCU is in standby mode? And when I use multimeter to measure current I got 10-20mA power consumption.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Has been cross-posted
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480833/stm32-standby-mode-power-consumption-is-too-high

Comment: I have listened to your advice

Comment: Your processor is in standby, but what else on your board draws current?  20mA would be about right if there are one or two LED lit for example.  What does it draw when it is not in standby?  Voltage on pins is no indication of stand-by - it depends when pins you are referring to and what they are connected to.

Comment: Clearly from your identical question on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480833/stm32-standby-mode-power-consumption-is-too-high, there are other components on this board that consume power - a USB bridge and an GNSS module, they will contribute significantly to your power budget - this is not a software question.